# Technique on finding element of $G/G'$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Take the group $G=D_6=\langle a,b \; ;\; a^3=1,b^2=1,b^{-1}ab=a^{-1}\rangle$ as example.

So we add the relation $ab=ba$ into the presentation of $G$ to form another group $H$.
Thus, $H=\{1,b\}$.
We can conclude that $G/G'=\{G',bG'\}$.

I wonder how this method works.
If $G$ is abelian, I know that $G'=1$, so $G/G'\cong G$.
But clearly $D_6$ is not an abelian group.

Note: $G'$ denotes the commutator subgroup of $G$.

Comment: what you have is $G=S_3$, $G'=A_3$ and $G/G'=\Bbb Z_2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its perfectly OK to add the relation $ba = ab$, or $b^{-1}ab=a$. If you simplify the relators one gets $G/G' = \langle a, b; a^3=1, b^2=1, b^{-1}ab = a^{-1}, b^{-1}ab =  a \rangle = \langle a, b; a^3=1, b^2=1, a = a^{-1}\rangle$ $ = \langle b; b^2=1\rangle$

Comment: The point I don't understand is why $G/G' = \langle a, b; a^3=1, b^2=1, b^{-1}ab = a^{-1}, b^{-1}ab =  a \rangle$

Comment: You just add the relator, just like you added the original relators to the free group, adding relators creates a quotient. Example $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}_2 = \langle a,b; b^2 = 1\rangle$ so $\mathbb{Z} \times $$ \mathbb{Z}_2/{2\mathbb{Z}} = \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$ =  $ \langle a,b; b^2 = 1, a^2 = 1\rangle$